# Polyline Offsetting using Clipper

Tags: graphics, geometry, maps, cad

I am using Clipper Library in which it is quite easy to do Polygon Offsetting, BUT MY PROBLEM IS TO DO POLYLINE OFFSETTING preferably using Clipper.

While searching on web I found a function called `OffsetPaths`, but the function offsets in two directions, that is it takes only positive argument as offset distance.

I can understand that unlike in closed Polygons where it is easy to specify direction, enlarging being positive and deflating as negative, Polylines do not have the same luxury. But my requirement is such.

Comment: Do you mean you want to offset open polygons?

Comment: Beware that "enlarging" and "deflating" have no meaning when it comes to polylines, better say offset to the left or to the right.

Comment: The offsetting operation is a truly non-trivial one, and you won't easily find solutions of the quality of Clipper and ready-made. If you have the skills, an option could be to adapt the existing offset function yourself.

Comment: Alberto : Yes, I am talking about open Polygons.
Yves Daoust : Thanks for the suggestion. Since I could not find any ready made library, I extended the clipper functionality by just making it a closed polygon.